# Swift: Find whether or not a member exists in Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to **Firebase** and pretty new to **Swift**, and I'm finding that I'm having trouble working with query's to retrieve data.

My goal is the following:

1. **To find which groups a specific user is a member of**

I tried to flatten the data by creating an object of only a group's members (using it's AutoId key).

```
{ groupMembers: 
        -KM0fTdaN2D_BKkvlk34:
             user1: true
             user2: true
             user3: true
         }
         -KM4ZaXCvALCV_gN74U8: {
             user3: true
             user4: true
         }
}
```

I tried to use the following code to run through a list of users, trying to only pull the relevant groups. Unfortunately I'm getting an InvalidQueryParameter error.

```
let groupMemberRef = rootRef.child("groupMembers")
func userFilter(list: [String]) {
// list is a list of different users (strings) I'm looking through the groups to try to find
for user in list {
    groupMemberRef.queryEqualToValue(true, childKey: user).observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        print(user)
        print(snapshot)
        print(snapshot.hasChild(user))
    })
}
```

Am I even going in the right direction? I've tried dozens of other strategies for chaining the methods without any luck. **Thank you for any help - I really a truly appreciate it!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store a list of group id's under each user, keeping track of the groups each use is in. 
Your DB structure should be something like:

```
Users: {
User_id_1: { 
Name: "user name",
...
Groups: {
group_id_1: true,
group_id_2: true,
...
}
}
},
Groups: {
group_id_1: {
user_id_1: true,
...
}
}
```

Comment: Considering my initial implementation after struggling defaulted to downloading all of my group data this is much better! I'm guessing that you'd opt to delete the groupMembers array that I have above after this switch (I didn't seem to need it after changing my code to this new model)?

Comment: Depending on your needs, the groups object should hold a group id and under that whatever properties for the group you might want, like "group name" or a counter that holds the number of people in it (this is better than counting the members each time) and in addition it should also have the "members" property with all the user id's